# Best/Fastest way to serialize a JSON object for JQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using the javascript library JQGrid to show a list of results.  I want to squeeze out every last bit of performance gain I can.  I am using the JQGrid url property to call a ASP.NET MVC ActionMethod.

In the action method I do my query then load an anonymous object with 3 int properties and 1 collection property:

```
public JsonResult GetDataRows(int dataId)
{
    IEnumerable myDataCollection = linqDB.DataRows.Where(i => i == dataId);
    var data = new
    {
        page = 1,
        total = 1,
        records = 3,
        rows = myDataCollection.ToList();
    };
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Is the MVC Json method the fastest way to serialize this data back to the javascript client script?  Is there something faster.

Comment: Is it *fast enough*? That is; *is* there a performance bottleneck? And *is* the bottleneck the JSON serialization presented here? I try not to "optimize" before having some form of measurement and (failing) requirements. If there is *lots* of data, maybe there is some sort of pagination technique?

Comment: Barely.  There are some things I cannot change due to the project having evolved over a decade thru many iterations.  I am asking based on the communities experience which is the fastest serialization.

Comment: Without numbers (read: without profiling) there is no performance problem. First, find the problem by using profiling - this will say where/what any bottlenecks are. If no problem can be found, move on. If there is a problem, but it's somewhere else, fix that instead. If profiling is setup then it would be trivial to test different serialization implementations and performance of such. When profiling make sure to test under realistic conditions and load.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look under the covers of the MVC framework and it looks like behind the JSON helper is the JavascriptSerializer.  While doing some testing I hit the maximum payload.

Since we already had the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library I added a custom ActionResult using its serializer.  Just using it to write to the browser not using it to serialise any JSON input...yet that is.  Here is the link to the ActionResult override to use the alternative serialiser.

[Json.NET ActionResult](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net)

Although this serializer is apparently faster than the standard ones, the fact that Microsoft WebAPI uses JSON.NET made me think this future proofs this one.  However based on my searching the web and readings, it sounds like the ServiceStack.Text serializer is the best.  Which apparently derives from the ProtoBuf-net serializer.

Comment: where did you read that it derives from protobuf-net? read her about the performance of ServiceStack.Text https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text go down to the `Performance` section